# Creating statistically correct ranking based on multiple variables

Tags: python, statistics, ranking, ranking-functions

I got a table with documents names with main columns being:

**Document Title, 
Creation Date, 
Number of Downloads 
Ranking (stars: from 0 to 5),

Number of times the documents was ranked**

The only fields that are **always** filled in with data are:
**Document Title, 
Creation Date**

What would be the correct formula for an overall ranking so that users could see what documents are the most popular taking into account:
**Creation Date,
Number of Downloads,
Ranking (stars: from 0 to 5), 
Number of times the documents was ranked**

For example, if a document was created yesterday with only one **ranking** of *5 stars* and *10* **downloads**, it cannot be of higher overall ranking higher than a document that's been available for **2 years** and with hundreds of **downloads** even though it only got 4 stars

Thanks